# Replace row values with multiple conditions in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Currently Im working on a project and got stuck in one problem. I have to replace row values of a column with two conditions in different columns. Suppose:

```
x   y     m     n
1  200P  Jan  Perm
1  200T  Feb  Temp  
1  300P  Jan  Perm
2  200T  Feb  Temp      
2  300T  Feb  Temp
3  300P  Jan  Perm
3  400P  Jan  Perm
```

I would like to change the values of column n based on x and y.

```
for each x
check the value of y and n, if the first value of y with T is 
Perm/Temp. Replace the rest of the values of unique x rows to that 
value.
```

I tried but when I execute the code it replaces all Temp to Perm or Perm to Temp. But I want it to change just the values of the rows for that unique x. Can someone please help me with this. I want my output to be like:

```
x   y     m     n
1  200P  Jan  Temp
1  200T  Feb  Temp  
1  300P  Jan  Temp
2  200T  Feb  Temp      
2  300T  Feb  Temp
3  300P  Jan  Perm
3  400P  Jan  Perm
```

I was trying to practice with another dataset with different conditions. For example:

```
a   b    c       d
1   1   0.4    Minor
1   1   0.4    Minor
1   4   0.2    Minor
1   2   2.4    Major
2   4   0.2    Minor
3   1   0.4    Minor
3   4   0.2    Minor
3   4   4.2    Major
```

I'm trying to replace 4 to 1 in column b with a condition that if it is 0.2 in column c. If 4 and 0.4 are in the same row, replace 4 to 1.

Comment: Could you please include your desired output in the text of your question? The explanation is a little murky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following code does what you want.
It creates a new column, `n2`, with the values of `n` corresponding to the first occurence of a `T` in `y`.

```
fun <- function(DF){
    i <- grep("T", DF$y)[1]
    DF$n2 <- DF$n
    if(!is.na(i)) DF$n2[seq_len(nrow(DF))[-seq_len(i - 1)]] <- DF$n[i]
    DF$n2
}

res <- dat    # work with a copy
res$n2 <- unlist(lapply(split(dat[c(1:2, 4)], dat$x), FUN = fun))
res
#  x    y   m    n   n2
#1 1 200P Jan Perm Perm
#2 1 200T Feb Temp Temp
#3 1 300P Jan Perm Temp
#4 2 200T Feb Temp Temp
#5 2 300T Feb Temp Temp
#6 3 300P Jan Perm Perm
#7 3 400P Jan Perm Perm
```

If you don't want that new column, just do

```
res$n <- res$n2
res <- res[-ncol(res)]
```

**EDIT.**

Apparently my original code was right. The following is what the OP asks for in the last comment.

```
fun2 <- function(DF){
    i <- grep("T", DF$y)[1]
    DF$n2 <- if(!is.na(i)) DF$n[i] else DF$n
    DF$n2
}

res2 <- dat    # work with a copy
res2$n2 <- unlist(lapply(split(dat[c(1:2, 4)], dat$x), FUN = fun))
res2
#  x    y   m    n   n2
#1 1 200P Jan Perm Temp
#2 1 200T Feb Temp Temp
#3 1 300P Jan Perm Temp
#4 2 200T Feb Temp Temp
#5 2 300T Feb Temp Temp
#6 3 300P Jan Perm Perm
#7 3 400P Jan Perm Perm
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
x   y     m     n
1  200P  Jan  Perm
1  200T  Feb  Temp  
1  300P  Jan  Perm
2  200T  Feb  Temp      
2  300T  Feb  Temp
3  300P  Jan  Perm
3  400P  Jan  Perm
", header = TRUE)
```

**EDIT 2.**

With the conditions in your question edit, it is much simpler, use a logical index.
Note that in your edit first you say to change column `b` value from 4 to if column `c` is `0.2` but then you say to change it if column `c` is `0.4`. The code below uses `0.2`.

```
inx <- dat2$b == 4 & dat2$c == 0.2
dat2$b[inx] <- 1
```

**DATA 2.**

```
dat2 <- read.table(text = "
a   b    c       d
1   1   0.4    Minor
1   1   0.4    Minor
1   4   0.2    Minor
1   2   2.4    Major
2   4   0.2    Minor
3   1   0.4    Minor
3   4   0.2    Minor
3   4   4.2    Major
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it on my dataset and it didn't change the values. Is it because of the datatype. I have x as num and the rest of them as char.

Comment: @Rahul I have read in the data as num and the other columns as `factor`. I have also tried to read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and the result is the same, so there must be something else going on. The output of my code seems right.

Comment: I found the bug. Your solution is not what I was expecting. The whole group of x that has 1 and so on, should be replaced by the new value. I looked into my dataset. Once it finds a T, it replaces the values after that, but it should replace the previous values as well. I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @Rahul Done, see if this is it.

Comment: Can you please read the added question and help me understand your code. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

We could also try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, {i1 <- grepl("T$", y)
            if(any(i1)) .I[which.max(i1):.N] } , x]$V1
```

Or

```
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[cumsum(grepl("T$", y))!=0], x]$V1
df1[i1, n := first(n), x]
df1
#   x    y   m    n
#1: 1 200P Jan Perm
#2: 1 200T Feb Temp
#3: 1 300P Jan Temp
#4: 2 200T Feb Temp
#5: 2 300T Feb Temp
#6: 3 300P Jan Perm
#7: 3 400P Jan Perm
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), y = c("200P", 
"200T", "300P", "200T", "300T", "300P", "400P"), m = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Jan"), n = c("Perm", "Temp", 
"Perm", "Temp", "Temp", "Perm", "Perm")), .Names = c("x", "y", 
"m", "n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::first` to find the `1st` occurrence of `y` having value with `T` and then replace all values of `n` with value from found row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(!is.na(first(grep("T$",y))), 
                            n[first(grep("T$",y))], n )) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   x    y   m    n
# 1 1 200P Jan Temp
# 2 1 200T Feb Temp
# 3 1 300P Jan Temp
# 4 2 200T Feb Temp
# 5 2 300T Feb Temp
# 6 3 300P Jan Perm
# 7 3 400P Jan Perm
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"x   y     m     n
1  200P  Jan  Perm
1  200T  Feb  Temp  
1  300P  Jan  Perm
2  200T  Feb  Temp      
2  300T  Feb  Temp
3  300P  Jan  Perm
3  400P  Jan  Perm",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```